# GCC Configure how to set with --without-multilib-list

Tags: linux, gcc

I an compiling gcc in Redhat, but I got the error of gnu/stubs-32.h, no such file or directory. I searched, and it seems that it has to do with missing 32bit libs. But I only want to complie 64 bit, so how can I use the option to skip the compiling for 32bit?

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring GCC with `--disable-multilib`. Make sure to set the target to `x86_64-...`. This disables all the multilib machinery and builds a single-architecture compiler.

Comment: Execuse me, but I am new to Linux, how to set the x86_64-...?